# Int to string: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'

Tags: c#, winforms, string, listview, int

I have a listView on my form. I want to add stuff to it durring the program is running.

This is the code I use

```
public void FillList(string[] Name,int[] empty,int[] Population,int[] Max,int[] Check,int size)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(Name[i]);

                item.SubItems.Add(empty[i].ToString); //error
                item.SubItems.Add(Population[i].ToString); //error
                item.SubItems.Add(Max[i].ToString);   //error

                if (Check != 1)
                    item.SubItems.Add("No");
                else
                    item.SubItems.Add("Yes");
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the parameter must be string and I tried `.ToString`, but I get this:

> Argument '1': cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'

Comment: John this is off topic but have you considered with this method to pass in a class made up of each of the sub items to add. I've added detail in a reply below

Comment: Stupid close reason. It helped me in a completely different context as the method group error is quite confusing and the root cause of this error, not anything more specific to the exact details of the question

Comment: @Jaloopa Agree completely; typical Stack Overflow and its massive overmoderation. This is an easy thing to miss for casual or new programmers in C#. The only difference between this closure and many others is that the others quite often have hundreds of upvotes for the answer instead of "only" 78.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You are missing the parentheses of the method call:

```
ToString()
```

Without the parentheses, the expression is a [method group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/886822/1968) — that is, a reference to one or more overloaded methods.

Answer (score 8):

You forgot the parentheses.

It should be `.ToString()`

Answer (score 1):

John this is off topic but have you considered with this method to pass in a class made up of each of the sub items to add. So:

```
class ListItem 
{
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public int Empty {get; set;}
 public int Population {get; set;}
 public int Max {get; set;}
 public bool Checked {get; set;}
}
```

That way you would need to have each of the items in the arrays passed in lined up. Trying to line up items in many arrays often make interfaces hard to use. Your method would look like

```
FillList(IList<ListItem> listItems)
{
if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(listItem .Name);

                item.SubItems.Add(listItem.Empty.ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(listItem.Population.ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(listItem.Max.ToString());

                item.SubItems.Add(listItem.Checked ? "No" : "Yes");

                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've just written this code straight in so there maybe some code cleanup required