# Delegate definition in C#

Tags: c#

Assuming I have the following delegate:

```
public delegate int TestD(int p);
```

Is there any difference between

```
TestD del = MyMethod;
```

and

```
TestD del = new TestD(MyMethod);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no difference: starting with C# 2.0, you can specify delegates using a [method group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c).

Note: In an unlikely case that you need 1.0 compatibility, the second syntax would be your only option.