# Callback from main function

Tags: c#

Below is my code in c#...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestPointer test = new TestPointer();
        test.function1(function2);   // Error here: The name 'function2' does not exist in     current context
    }
}

class TestPointer
{
    private delegate void fPointer(); // point to every functions that it has void as return value and with no input parameter 
    public void function1(fPointer ftr)
    {
        fPointer point = new fPointer(ftr);
        point();
    }

    public void function2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bla");
    }
}
```

How can I call a callback function by passing function refernce in main function?...
I'm new to c#

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? (This looks like _C#_, not C++, by the way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test.function1(test.function2)` should do it.

You'll also need

```
public delegate void fPointer();
```

instead of

```
private delegate void fPointer();
```

Comment: Ah, you have to mark your `delegate` as `public` too in order for it to be used outside the class. It now compiles and runs fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with an Action:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestPointer test = new TestPointer();
            test.function1(() => test.function2());   // Error here: The name 'function2' does not exist in     current context

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class TestPointer
    {
        private delegate void fPointer(); // point to every functions that it has void as return value and with no input parameter 
        public void function1(Action ftr)
        {
            ftr();
        }

        public void function2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bla");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with your code:

```
    TestPointer test = new TestPointer();
    test.function1(function2);
```

Here, there is no variable called `function2` in scope. What you want to do is call it like this:

```
    test.function1(test.function2);
```

The `test.function2` is in fact a [method group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c), which in this case will be converted by the compiler to a delegate. On to the next problem:

```
private delegate void fPointer(); 
public void function1(fPointer ftr)
```

You declared the delegate as private. It should be public. A [delegate is a special kind of type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but it is still a type (you can declare variables of 'em, which is exactly what you do when you declare the argument to `function1`). When declared as private, the type is not visible from outside the class `TestPointer` and thus can not be used as an argument to a public method.

Finally, not really an error but the way you call the delegate can be simplified:

```
    ftr();
```

So here's your corrected code:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestPointer test = new TestPointer();
        test.function1(test.function2);   
    }
}

class TestPointer
{
    public delegate void fPointer(); 
    public void function1(fPointer ftr)
    {
        ftr();
    }

    public void function2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bla");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `function2` `static` or pass `text.function2`.

Comment: If you make `function2` `static` you'll need to pass `TestPointer.function2`. If not, you'll need to pass `test.function2`, not `text.funxtion2`.