# '+' not allowed to concatenate string or method group

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a method group in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c)

What is the problem with the '+' signal to concatenate a string?

This is print screen of my problem:

http://pbrd.co/UtDf61

```
Json(new
{
    dom = "RegistroUsuario",
    type = "showErrorToast",
    msg = "Erro: " + e,
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

string jsScript = "closeAndRedirectJson(" + Json + ")";
```

The error I am receiving is

> Operation '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and
>   'method group'

Comment: `Json` appears to be a function. A function is not a string. Also, we don’t want a link to a screenshot of your problem - please just include the code in your question and write out what the error is.

Comment: Please try not to post a link to an image, but instead post your code inside of the question itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error is clearly telling you, `Json` is neither a string nor an object.

Rather, it's a *method group* – a "reference" to function.
Unlike Javascript, C# functions are not objects; you can only use a method group to create a delegate instance.  (which isn't what you want anyway)

If you want to convert your earlier object to a usable string of JSON, you'll need to use the `JavascriptSerializer` class directly.

The `Json()` method returns a `JsonResult` instance which can only be used to write the JSON to the response body; it's useless here.

Comment: Thanks.. I´ll accept the awnser as soon as I am able to!

Comment: Of course, when `+` denotes delegate combination, one of its operands _can_ be a method group. Maybe if `f` is a `Func<object, string, JsonResult>` or whatever signature is needed, then `f + Json` is allowed.

Comment: @GuilhermeLongo: If you say so... :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following:

```
static string X() { return "hello"; }
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(X + "goodbye");
}
```

Do you see the problem? The code concatenates *the method X* with the string "goodbye". But a method is not something that can be concatenated to a string!  The intention was to *call the method*. The correct code is:

```
    Console.WriteLine(X() + "goodbye");
```

It is not clear to me from your program fragment what you intend to concatenate in there, but `Json` is a method, not something that can be concatenated with a string.

Incidentally, the reason that the compiler is using the somewhat confusing term "method group" in the error is because you might be in this situation:

```
static string X(int y) { return "hello"; }
static string X(double z) { return "hello"; }
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(X + "goodbye");
}
```

Now it is unclear *which method* `X` is referring to, and in fact, the C# language says that the expression `X` refers to *both* methods. Such an expression is classified as a "method group". The process of *overload resolution* picks a unique best method out of a method group.

Comment: It's actually worse than that; `Json()` returns neither a string nor an object with a usable `ToString()`.

Answer (score -6):

It's a `function`. Not a `string`. You can't use it with concatenation.

Comment: Wrong.  That would compile too.  It's a method group.