# Why it is not possible to assign a delegate to a method group?

Tags: c#, delegates

Having the following class:

```
class C {
    public void OneMethod(string s) { 
    }

    public void ChangeMethods() {
        OneMethod = delegate(string s) { };
    }
}
```

The compiler says:

> Error 1   Cannot assign to 'OneMethod' because it is a 'method group'

Why is that? Should I create a method group instead?

Comment: What are you trying to do? This code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c

Comment: Because I wanted to change the method behaviour, I thought that was a simple way to do that (if it was possible)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply can't change how a class behaves like this.

Method groups are only used in method invocation expressions and when creating delegate instances.

If you want a class which can behave dynamically like this, you should perhaps look at [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx). Or if you want to be able to make your `OneMethod` class do something based on a delegate which varies, you can easily hook that up simply enough using a field of the relevant delegate type:

```
class C {
    private Action<string> action = delegate {};

    public void OneMethod(string s) { 
        action(s);
    }

    public void ChangeMethods() {
        action = delegate(string s) { };
    }
}
```

It's *somewhat* unusual to want to do this, admittedly.

Comment: This idea is what I usually do. I think I got this idiom from javascript.

Comment: @Vandell: Then stick with it. .NET simply doesn't support changing method implementations directly like you were apparently trying. JavaScript is a completely different model.

Comment: This is fine. If you want to also "combine" delegates, that is `action += delegate(string s) { ExtraWork(s); };` with `+=` instead of `=`, maybe you shouldn't use `Action<in T>` because delegate combination doesn't work with contravariant generic delegates. But I must admit, there is absolutely nothing in the question that would indicate that combining (`+`) delegate instances is relevant (or that the contravariance is going to be important).