# Error when compiling?

Tags: c#, .net

How could I fix the error upon compiling the short code.

Here is the code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      int a = 5;
      MessageBox.Show(a.ToString);
 }
```

It gives me back this 2 errors:

> Error 1 The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string)' has some invalid
>   arguments`Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to
>   'string'`

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `()` at the end of `ToString`

```
MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
```

The error you are getting:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'
```

That is because `MessageBox.Show` expects a string type parameter and since you forgot to specify `()` at the end, `a.ToString` is a method group.

Got the following for [Method group by Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/886840/961113) from a question on Stackoverflow.

> A method group is the name for a set of methods (that might be just
>   one) - i.e. in theory the ToString method may have multiple overloads
>   (plus any extension methods): ToString(), ToString(string format), etc
>   - hence ToString by itself is a "method group".

Answer (score 2):

you lack `()` in the `ToString()` method,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      int a = 5;
      MessageBox.Show(a.ToString()); // <<== HERE
 }
```