# Is is possible to wrap method parameters in C# as functions without a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, func

Lets say I have a method with the following signature:

```
public void MyMethod(Func<int> expression)
{
    // Does work
}
```

And I call this method as follows:

```
int intProperty = 7;
MyMethod(() => intProperty);
```

Is their some way that I could call this method without using the lambda? So I want it to look like this:

```
MyMethod(intProperty);
```

It does not matter to me if the method signature has to change - I am kind of counting on that. The reason I am trying to do this is because you can inspect additional information about the initial property when its passed in as a function that I need to be able to access.

I don't believe that using Reflection inside of MyMethod would work here, as I want information about the original parameter. Their are ways of getting information such as its name from a function, which is what I want to be able to retrieve. I am already able to do this. So, in the example above, MyMethod would be able to tell that the name of the property that was passed in was named intProperty.

NOTE: This is a simplified example. I am well aware I could just pass in the property if that's all I wanted. BUT I want additional information about the original property that the Func is capturing here, such as its original name.

Comment: I'm sorry but there isn't a built in way to do that.

Comment: The last example is equivalent to `MyMethod(int)` so you can do just that.

Comment: What do you mean by "you can inspect additional information about the initial property when its passed in as a function?" Perhaps your example requires some clarification.

Comment: I have to ask.  Why do you want to capture the original name of the variable that was passed in?  I can't think of a legitimate reason to need to know that.

Comment: I am creating a library that needs to know the original name of a property for parameter validation in the case that exceptions need to be thrown. I want to be able to include that original name in the exception that is raised.

Comment: What are you going to print if the user calls `MyMethod(intProperty+2)`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it for properties, but you can do it for property-like getter methods. Starting with C#3.0, you can build delegates implicitly using [*method groups*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/886822/335858):

```
public void MyMethod(Func<int> expression) {
    // Does work
}
public int GetProperty() {
    return 123;
}
pubic void Test() {
    MyMethod(GetProperty /* NO PARENTHESES HERE!!! */);
}
```

Dropping the parentheses after the method name converts an invocation expression into a method group. Unfortunately, this means that there is no comparable syntax for properties, because accessing properties does not require parentheses.

Comment: I've posted another answer like this before but get downvoted. After OP revised, I post a new answer.

Comment: @KenKin I do not know who downvoted your first answer, but I doubt that it had to do with the substance of your answer: the content is absolutely correct. What might have triggered a downvote was lack of explanation in what you have posted: not everyone with the right to vote knows about method groups :)

Answer (score 0):

**Using expressions**

You mentioned that it doesn't matter if the method signature has to change. So why not change the method signature to:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T source, Expression<Func<T, int>> expression)
{
    // Evaluate expression
}

MyMethod(this, x => x.property);
```

I won't go into too much detail here on parsing expression trees, but for more information, see this question on SO:

[Retrieving Property name from lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression)

**Using reflection**

You can use reflection to get information about the property as well. Drop the `source` parameter if you don't need to get the actual value of the property.

```
public void MyMethod(object source, string propertyName)
{
    var pi = source.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    if (pi == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("property not found");
    }

    MyMethod(source, pi);
}

public void MyMethod(object source, PropertyInfo property)
{
    // Evaluate property
}

MyMethod(this, "Property");
```

Comment: As noted in the question, I want to be able to get additional information about the original property, such as the original name. This can be done by passing in functions.

Comment: @lehn0058 Sorry I wasn't sure if that was what you meant. I've updated my answer to something that should be more useful to you.

Comment: This might be closer. There is still the lambda call when using MyMethod, which the end goal is to remove. However, I was thinking that using Expression might be able to achieve this somehow.

Comment: @lehn0058 I added a note on reflection that might help you out.

Comment: If I use reflection at that level, I will get the information about the property inside of MyMethod. I need to keep the information about the original property that was passed into MyMethod. I will update the question to specify this explicitly.