# ToCharArray function not working correctly

Tags: c#, char, arrays

I'm working on a program and I need to turn a string into a array so I can turn each letter in that string to some thing else but I can't get to work it keeps giving me the following error.

**Error :**

> "Cannot convert method group 'To Char Array' to non-delegate type 'char[]'. Did you intendto invoke the method?"

**C# code :**

```
char [] typedArray = typed.ToCharArray;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ToCharArray` is a method, not a property, so it's invocation requires parenthesis:

```
char[] typedArray = typed.ToCharArray();
```

`typed.ToCharArray` (without the parenthesis) is a [method group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/886822/87698), which could be converted to a delegate, but that's not what you want to do here.