# String = (Convert(String) - 1).ToString

Tags: c#, string

Well, I need to subtract the number from a string, and in the end she should continue being a string ...

I try:

```
PStruct.character[Index, PStruct.player[Index].SelectedChar].Y = 
  (Convert.ToInt32(PStruct.character[Index, PStruct.player[Index].SelectedChar].Y) - 1)
 .ToString;
```

Character.Y is a string.

The error:
   **Cannot convert method group "ToString" to non-delegate type "string".**

Anyone have tips or a solution?

Comment: You want ToString(), not ToString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parenthesis to [*invoke/call* a method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx):

```
expr.ToString()
```

Without parenthesis it (`ToString`) is treated as a ["method group"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c), which is useful in some cases - but not here.

Answer (score 0):

As written, you are trying to treat a function `ToString` as a type `string`.

As the comment mentioned, you probably meant to write `ToString()`.