# Extension methods on Action/Func for regular method

Tags: c#, action, extension-methods

I am a programmer, and I am lazy. Currently I am working with some OpenAL wrappers in C#. Every time I call an OpenAL method, I have to request the error from OpenAL using `GetError` and if there is one, I throw an exception. It didn't take long until I added a static helper class containing the following function:

```
    public static void Check()
    {
        ALError error;
        if ((error = AL.GetError()) != ALError.NoError)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(AL.GetErrorString(error));
    }
```

This worked for a while, but I wanted more. So, after a while, I came up with the following methods:

```
    public static void Call(Action function)
    {
        function();
        ALHelper.Check();
    }

    public static void Call<TParameter>(Action<TParameter> function, TParameter parameter)
    {
        function(parameter);
        ALHelper.Check();
    }

    public static TReturn Eval<TReturn>(Func<TReturn> function)
    {
        var val = function();
        ALHelper.Check();
        return val;
    }

    public static TReturn Eval<TParameter, TReturn>(Func<TParameter, TReturn> function, TParameter parameter)
    {
        var val = function(parameter);
        ALHelper.Check();
        return val;
    }
```

This worked great, but I was still not happy with how exactly the code looked when used, so I decided to take it one step further: I turned the above methods into extension methods. As I knew I could pass methods as the `Action` and `Func` parameters, I thought it would work as well for extension methods, turning the ugly `handles = ALHelper.Eval(AL.GenBuffers, amount)` into a more elegant `handles = AL.GenBuffers.Eval(amount)`.

Sadly, I was welcomed with an exception once I started using this: Expression denotes a `method group', where a`variable', `value' or`type' was expected.

Somewhat saddened that this doesn't work, I actually got curious as to why this wouldn't work. What exactly is the reason you can pass a method as `Action` or `Func`, but using extension methods doesn't work? Is this a limitation of the Mono compiler I am using (.NET 4.0) I am using, or is there something else going on inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `handles = ALHelper.Eval(AL.GenBuffers, amount)`, `AL.GenBuffers` isn't a delegate of any type. Overload resolution considers all overloads of `ALHelper.Eval` and finds exactly one delegate type to which the expression `AL.GenBuffers` can be converted.

When you write `handles = AL.GenBuffers.Eval(amount)`, `AL.GenBuffers` still isn't a delegate of any type, so `AL.GenBuffers.Eval` doesn't match any methods, and overload resolution cannot help find the best match.

You would be able to write `new Func<T, TResult>(AL.GenBuffers).Eval(...)`, as in principle, extension methods do work on delegate types, but that's worse than what you already had.

This is not specific to Mono.

What I would do instead is create a class (let's say `MyAL`), and provide wrappers for all of `AL`'s functions. Callers can then say `handles = MyAL.GenBuffers(amount);`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already expected something similar to this, but it is good to see this explained to detail. I indeed already considered making my own wrapper class for AL, which might alright help with things a lot, but for now I'll stick with passing the function as argument.

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstand the concept of extension method.They are used to extend *types*. In this case  `AL.GenBuffers` is a method, it isn't a `Func` or `Action.`It's signature may be compatible with them but it doesn't mean it is a func or action or any other kind of delegate type. In your example you are able to pass it like `AL.GenBuffers` because of the [*method group conversions*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c). When compiler see the method signature is compatible it converts it to `delegate` type.