# Foreach cannot operate on a 'method group'. Did you intend to invoke the 'method group'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I'm pretty new to C# and I'm getting an error I can't quite figure out?

I have a view where I want to loop a series of nodes, so I'm trying do to this:

```
@foreach (var crumb in Model.Breadcrumb)
{
  //My code
}
```

As in my viewmodel I have this:

```
public IEnumerable<LinkModel> Breadcrumb(IPublishedContent content) {
    //Do logic. 
     return GetFrontpage(content, true).Reverse().Select(item => new LinkModel {
        Target = "",
        Text = item.Name,
        Url = item.Url
    }); 
}

private static IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> GetFrontpage(IPublishedContent content, bool includeFrontpage = false)
{
    var path = new List<IPublishedContent>();

    while (content.DocumentTypeAlias != "frontpage")
    {
        if (content == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("No frontpage found");
        }
        path.Add(content);
        content = content.Parent;
    }
    if (includeFrontpage)
    {
        path.Add(content);
    }
    return path;
}
```

Comment: Which line does it point to in the compile error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Model.Breadcurmb` is a method and not a property or field, so call it as below

```
     @foreach (var crumb in Model.Breadcrumb(content))
```

Answer (score 6):

When you don't add parentheses compiler treats the method as [*method group*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c). If you want to call the method and iterate over the result then use:

```
@foreach (var crumb in Model.Breadcrumb(/* your parameters */))
```

Comment: Made a list in yours model for group by name and list render into foreach