# How to register for an EventHandler when there is a method with the same name

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have an instance of the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in a variable

```
Application word;
```

Now I want to register a method for the `Quit` Eventhandler.

```
word.Quit += onWordQuit;
```

The problem is, that there is also a method called `Quit`. The compiler complains that

> "Cannot assign to 'Quit' because it is a method group.
>   Reference 'Quit' is a 'method group'. The assignment target must be an assignable variable, property or indexer

I found this [blog post from 2004](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/eric_carter/2004/09/20/problems-when-a-method-and-event-name-are-the-same-when-using-c/) about this subject. 
But when I cast `Quit` like so:

```
(ApplicationEvents4_QuitEventHandler)word.Quit += onWordQuit;
```

I get the error

> No overload for `Quit` matches delegate
>   ApplicationEvents4_QuitEventHandler.

How can I register to the `Quit` Event Handler in this case?

Comment: Have you tryed `word.Quit += Quit` as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840120/cannot-assign-to-method-because-it-is-a-method-group) answer suggest?

Comment: There is no `Quit` event handler. If you look on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationclass.quit?view=word-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Word_ApplicationClass_Quit_System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__) you'll see that `Quit` is a void method. You can see other entries at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationclass?view=word-pia) which show the various ApplicationEventsX_Event_Quit events

Comment: That does not work either. `Cannot choose method from method group. Did you intend to invoke the method?`

Comment: @A Friend: Intellisense shows both a method and an EventHandler with the name Quit.This is why I asked the question. But I see that the documentation does not confirm the existence of this EventHandler.

Comment: @A Friend: I am using the [Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationevents4_event.quit?view=word-pia) class and not the ApplicationClass. The Application class does have a Quit event.

Comment: `Application` is an interface, which is implemented into `ApplicationClass`

Comment: You must need to get the cast right, it is ((ApplicationEvents4_Event)word).Quit += yadayada;

Comment: @Hans Passant: You nailed it. I just found that [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/593a5978-c249-4ecb-9c00-855d550a8818/applicationquit-event-in-word?forum=vsto). Thank you. Do you want to post that as an answer and I will accept it as the correct one.

Comment: Just share what you discovered in your own post and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to register for the EventHandler in this case is (as Hans Passant and [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/593a5978-c249-4ecb-9c00-855d550a8818/applicationquit-event-in-word?forum=vsto) pointed out) is:

```
((ApplicationEvents4_Event)word).Quit += onWordQuit;
```