# Calling a method from a LINQ select

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to understand how this method call works in a `Linq statement`.
I have a line of code such as:

```
foreach (var model in myDataList.Select(RenderMyData))
{
    pPoint.CreateStuff(model, true);
}
```

and RenderMyData looks like this:

```
    protected PowerPoint.MyModel RenderMyData(CustomData myData)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
```

How does the CustomData object get passed to the RenderMyData method?
If I wanted to add another parameter to the RenderMyData method (like a bool) then how I can pass that in the linq select?

Comment: It is possible by method group conversion. [This SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c) should explain you more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an implicit  conversion from a method group (`RenderMyData`) to a compatible delegate type (`Func<CustomData, MyModel>` in this case). It is equivalent to:

```
var model in myDataList.Select(d => RenderMyData(d))
```

if you add a parameter you can do:

```
var model in myDataList.Select(d => RenderMyData(d, otherParam))
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation