# C# equivalent to Java 8 "method reference"

Tags: java, c#, java-8

I recently had the opportunity to tweak some Java code and was able to take advantage of some new Java 8 features. In one particular case I needed to get a List of (String) `.Name` properties from a List of objects. A simplified example of what I did was:

```java
// sample data: <Thing> objects have a single String property called "Name" 
List<Thing> thingList =
    new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Thing("Thing1"), new Thing("Thing2")));

// first pass
List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
thingList.forEach(x -> nameList.add(x.getName()));

// refinement 1: use stream, map, and collect
List<String> nameList1 =
    thingList.stream().map(x -> x.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());

// refinement 2: use "Thing::getName" method reference
List<String> nameList2 =
    thingList.stream().map(Thing::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I was curious to see how those approaches would translate to C#, and I got

```cs
// sample data: <Thing> objects have a single String property called "Name"
var thingList = new List<Thing> { new Thing("Thing1"), new Thing("Thing2") };

// first pass
var nameList = new List<String>();
thingList.ForEach(x => nameList.Add(x.Name));

// refinement 1: use Select and ToList
List<String> nameList1 = thingList.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

What I haven't found (yet?) is a C# equivalent of "refinement 2" to replace the Lambda expression with something (a little bit) more concise. Is there a C# equivalent to the Java 8 "method reference" in this case, given that I'm trying to get a *property* of each object (which in Java is done using a `getProperty` *method*)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would have to declare a method outside of `Thing` (or a static `Thing` method), then you could pass a method-group reference to it:

```
private string GetName(Thing thing)
{
    return thing.Name;
}

...

List<String> nameList1 = thingList.Select(GetName).ToList();
```

In C# 6, you can also use an expression-bodied function to save a couple of lines:

```
private string GetName(Thing thing) => thing.Name;
```

Comment: But `.Select(GetName)` is a syntax sugar that looks like a method reference, essentially it's still `.Select(x => GetName(x))`.

Comment: Pretty sure it's a method reference. But so what if it's sugar? OP just wants shorter code. What's the difference?

Comment: @Danny Chen: “essentially” Java 8’s method reference also is syntactic sugar for a lambda expression invoking the specified method. Though, technically, it’s the other way round, a lambda expression is syntactic sugar for a method reference to an additional method holding the lambda’s body.

Answer (score 7):

**C#** has an equivalent feature called **Method Group**.

See more:
[What is a method group in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c)

Sample:

```
private static int[] ParseInt(string s)
{
    var t = ParseString(s);
    var i = t.Select(x => int.Parse(x));
    return i.ToArray();
}
```

With metod group:

```
private static int[] ParseInt(string s)
{
    var t = ParseString(s);
    var i = t.Select(int.Parse);
    return i.ToArray();
}
```