# Usage list.ForEach in C#

Tags: c#, list, collections, foreach, lambda

Lets have:

```
List<double> inputs,outputs;
```

Is any difference between this:

```
inputs.Clear();
outputs.ForEach(inputs.Add);
```

and this:

```
inputs.Clear();  
outputs.ForEach(x => inputs.Add(x));
```

1) I assume that both options will first clear list of inputs and than take all values in list of outputs and put them into list of inputs. 
2) Both options looks like they are equivalent. Am I right? Is any difference between them?

Comment: They will be compiled to the same code. The first form you've used is called method group.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a method group in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c)

Comment: Equivalent.  But I think the lambda is more readable than the method group.

Comment: They are equivalent _so long as there are not multiple overloads of_ `Add`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no difference. They'll most likely be compiled to the same IL code.

However, in my opinion, this form

```
inputs.Clear();  
outputs.ForEach(x => inputs.Add(x));
```

shows your intent more clearly. I probably would avoid this altogether though and just use a `foreach` loop to add each element to `inputs`. But it ultimately comes down to your personal preference.

Comment: If you are using multiple ForEach'es in your code, it would help in terms of readability to be consistent in using one or the other.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Yeah good point. But I'm not gonna to mix it. I'm just wanted know the behaviour of that constructions, because they are new to me.