# Ways of using AddListener

Tags: c#

I'm wondering what's is the difference between this two uses of **Add listener** on c#. On my script, both are working. But I guess there should be a difference ? Thanks !

```
btn.onClick.AddListener(() => PickAPuzzle()); 

btn.onClick.AddListener (PickAPuzzle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are identical, the first is using a slightly longer form of passing an explicit overload whereas the second is using a method group, where the compiler chooses the correct overload (see: [What is a Method Group in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/886840)).

AddListener() is one and the same, and the delegates they receive are effectively the same.  The difference is syntactical shorthand.

Comment: Isn't the first line a delegate to a method which will call the method, and the second a direct delegate to the method ? if so, won't the second line be (very, very slightly) more efficient ?

Comment: @gobes another consideration is if compiler will optimize this and produce the same compiled code

Comment: @gobes I misspoke a bit.  Both effectively produce the same delegate--one is more explicit, the other less so.