# How can I bypass display image in c# if the directory the image is supposed to be in doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an aspx page that I am displaying image from codehind c#.
Every item has it's own directory with images inside if there were any uploaded.
It works fine except if the directory doesn't exist for a certain item, I get a return error "Could not find part of the path....
In some cases the directory will not exist because there are no images assigned to the item.  What should I include in my code to ignore this if there is no directory for the item?

Below is the code used to display the images:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/Test/Files/Item" + ItemNumber + "/"));
List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
files.Add(new ListItem(fileName, "/Test/Files/Item" + ItemNumber + "/" + fileName));
}
```

Comment: `If(File.Exists(filePath)){//Existing code inside loop here}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`File.Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) method to filter out image files that are missing:

```
foreach (string filePath in filePaths.Where(File.Exists)) {
    ... //
}
```

You need to add `using System.Linq` and `using System.IO` in order for the above to compile.

**Note:** The above uses [*method groups*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/886822/335858) for creating lambda expressions. `Where(File.Exists)` is a shorthand syntax for `Where(f => File.Exists(f))`