# What is special about the System.Type objects? And what are method group names?

Tags: c#

I'm reading the C# Docs and I've encountered these sentences:

> although a namespace name is classified as an expression, it does not
>   evaluate to a value and therefore can never be the final result of any
>   expression. You cannot pass a namespace name to a method parameter, or
>   use it in a new expression, or assign it to a variable. You can only
>   use it as a sub-expression in a larger expression. The same is true
>   for types (as distinct from System.Type objects), method group names
>   (as distinct from specific methods)

What exactly does "The same is true for types (as distinct from System.Type objects)" mean? Can you give me an example of this with `System.Type`? Does it have something to do with reflection?

Also what are "method group names" and "specific methods"?

Comment: Most of the things you mentioned can only appear in an expression as the left operand of a member access expression (the dot `.`)  Types can, in addition to being the left operand of a member access (to reach static members) also appear inside of cast notation, with `is`, `as`, and `typeof` operators, and as actual generic parameters.

Comment: No, `System.Type` objects are what you get when you use the `typeof` operator.  A type name or placeholder goes in, a `System.Type` instance comes out.

Comment: "Method group names" already answered here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c

Comment: This seems to be an English question rather than a coding question. It is simply worded to clarify that they are not talking about `System.Type` when they say types, but actual defined types such as classes, structs, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It means that not all expressions start out as values.  Some expressions are namespaces or types.

Consider what might appear on the right side of:

```
var foo = some_expression;
```

Most expressions would stand in well for `some_expression` because most expressions are values.  But some expressions are not.  Such as `int` or `System`

```
var foo = int; // ERROR
```

Yet types can be part of an expression that *is* a value:

```
var foo1 = 42 is int; // foo1 is a bool
var foo2 = typeof(int); // foo2 is a System.Type object
var foo3 = default(int); // foo3 is an int
```

Similarly, namespaces like `System` aren't values, but they *are* expressions.  You can use namespace expressions to get other expressions - for example, using the dot `.` operator to form a *type* expression.  `System.String` is an expression that is a type.  And, as before, you might further write it as `typeof(System.String)` to get an expression that is an actual value that you could assign to a variable.

I suggest looking at Expression trees, as used in LINQ or Lambda expressions, or the way you craft expressions when emitting IL. That might really help you get a handle on how the language (and the compiler) treat expressions and why the grammar is defined the way it is.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions(v=vs.110).aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expressions