# LINQ: Select on dynamic list doesn't compile

Tags: c#, linq, generics, dynamic

Assume I have a method like this:

```
static string ToString(dynamic d)
{
    return (string)d.ToString();
}
```

And for example that I have `var tmp = new List<dynamic> { 1, "2", 345 };`

Why does

```
IEnumerable<string> test = tmp.Select(ToString);
```

compile fine, but

```
IEnumerable<string> test = tmp.Select(x => ToString(x));
```

doesn't?

Error:

```
CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>'  to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

This holds true on VS 2015 and VS 2017 against all >=4.5.0 frameworks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've encountered [dynamic contagion](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/11/08/dynamic-contagion-part-two/). A `dynamic` could be anything, so any method or property on it could return anything. Any method you pass it to could be anything, because when you pass a `dynamic` as a parameter, overload resolution happens at runtime (this can be exploited if you hate the people who'll have to maintain your code).

If you hover the mouse over `Select`, it's of type `Select<dynamic, string>`, so it returns `IEnumerable<String>`. Because `ToString(dynamic d)` has an explicit cast to `string` in the `return`, and returns type `string`, the compiler can be assured that `ToString` really is returning a string.

```
IEnumerable<string> test = tmp.Select(ToString);
```

Incidentally, if we make these changes to ToString(), the above will still compile and the lambda version still won't:

```
    static string ToString(object d)
    {
        //  Remove the cast to string
        return d.ToString();
    }
```

The contagion is introduced when we create `tmp` as `List<dynamic>`.

In lambda version that won't compile, hovering the mouse shows that we're actually calling `Select<dynamic, dynamic>` which returns `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.

Overload resolution is done at runtime when you pass `dynamic`. The compiler can't guarantee at compile time what method will actually be called or what it will return. Intellisense thinks `ToString` is your static method, but the compiler doesn't trust that to remain true.

```
IEnumerable<string> test2 = tmp.Select(x => ToString(x));
```

This compiles, because we have a cast where overload resolution won't affect it.

```
IEnumerable<string> test3 = tmp.Select(x => (string)ToString(x));
```

Jonathon Chase kindly notes in comments that we make it compile by explicitly passing type parameters to `Select`:

```
IEnumerable<string> test4 = tmp.Select<dynamic, string>(x => ToString(x));
```

**The important question, in my view, is why your first case compiles.** My cautious guess is that because you're passing a reference to the method rather than calling it, dynamic overload resolution doesn't happen.

Consider this a placeholder until somebody with deeper understanding takes an interest in the question.

Comment: I think it's really interesting that `Select(ToString)` is inferred as `Select<dynamic,string>` whereas `Select(x => ToString(x))` is inferred as `Select<dynamic,dynamic>`. I think you're correct that overload resolution is probably the culprit, given the murkiness of it's rules with odd corner cases.

Comment: Which, having realized that was the case, you can get it to compile with `tmp.Select<dynamic,string>(x => ToString(x));`

Answer (score 2):

I will not repeat answer made by Ed about "dynamic contagion". But will try to shed some light on the reason of the first case successful compilation.

Here

```
IEnumerable<string> test = tmp.Select(ToString);
```

`ToString` is a method group – sugaring feature which allows you to pass a method as a delegate with appropriate signature using some kind of a shortcut. Some additional info may be found in this thread [What is a method group in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c).

This actually works by the means of creating a new delegate instance under the cover. Therefore your code is pretty equivalent to

```
Func<dynamic, string> toString = new Func<dynamic, string>(ToString);
IEnumerable<string> test = tmp.Select(toString);
```

As you can see we have an explicit delegate return type here, and it's not dynamic, thus we shouldn't worry about dynamic contagion.

Comment: In this case, _why_ does the method group conversion choose (the equivalent of, at least) `Func<dynamic, string>`?

Comment: @JonathonChase this is the only overload available at compile time. Signature may be `Func<dynamic, dynamic>` due to variance, but what's the matter if delegate target will be `ToString : dynamic -> string` in any case