# Using object/method name inside Linq method?

Tags: c#

What is the name of the "construction" at line 3 in which Contains is invoked, but without parentheses? Is it some kind of syntactic sugar?

```
string current = "02";
string[] list = {"00", "01", "02", "03", "10"};
if (list.Any(current.Contains)) {
  // logic
}
```

I just can not figure out why and how it works nor what it is called?

Comment: It is method group. And it is not invoked, but converted to compatible delegate type. https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/conversions.md#method-group-conversions

Comment: You're not calling `current.Contains`. You're passing a reference to `current.Contains`. It is then called, via that reference, by `list.Any()` -- or perhaps by some other method that `list.Any()` passes it to. A very helpful exercise would be for you to write your own equivalent of `List.Any()`.

Comment: There are no parantheses, as you are there not executing contains, but "passing" the method reference to the Any-function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may recall that you can subscribe to events by doing this:

```
something.SomeEvent += SomeHandler;
```

That's syntactic sugar for:

```
something.SomeEvent += new EventHandler(SomeHandler);
```

This creates a new `EventHandler` instance (`EventHandler` is a delegate type), which uses the method `SomeHandler`.

Something similar is going on here.

`list.Any` takes a `Func<T, bool>`, which is a delegate type. Therefore you need to pass it an instance of `Func<T, bool>`.

When you write:

```
list.Any(x => current.Contains(x))
```

the compiler creates a new method (which takes a `string`, returns a `bool`, and just calls `current.Contains`), and does something like this:

```
list.Any(new Func<string, bool>(GeneratedMethod))
```

Now, you can also create that `Func<string, bool>` delegate instance from an explicit method yourself, just as in the `EventHandler` example:

```
list.Any(new Func<string, bool>(current.Contains))
```

Or, you can leave off the `new Func<string, bool>` and the compiler will generate it for you, again just as in the earlier example:

```
list.Any(current.Contains)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `list.Any()` function takes a predicate function as the first parameter. Normally this is an inline lambda function like `list.Any(s => s == "01")`, but of cause you can pass in a properly defined function like in your example.

`s => s == "01"` and `current.Contains` have the same signature. They both take a string as the only input parameter and return a boolean. Therefore they can both be used as the predicate in the `list.Any()` function.

For more information about method groups check out [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c) and for information about Lambda function [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)