# Pass instance method as a parameter without an instance

Tags: c#

I was wondering if, in C#, one could pass an instance method as a delegate without an instance. For reference, this is possible in Java by doing `example(InstanceClass::InstanceMethod)`. The compiler then turns this into the equivalent of a `Func<InstanceClass, ReturnType>` which calls `InstanceMethod()` on the provided `InstanceClass` like so: `item=>item.InstanceMethod()`. Is this possible in C# and if it is, how would one do it?

Edit: To clarify, I am asking how I can pass the method in C# without using a lambda expression. The Lambda expression given is an example of what the compiler would turn the call into. Just passing the method instead of using a Lambda expression would be useful if the method had many arguments

Edit 2: Here is an example to illustrate my question. Java:

```java
class Instance{
    public void InstanceMethod(){System.out.println("Hello World");}
    public static void Example(){
        ArrayList<Instance> list = new ArrayList<>(5);
        list.add(new Instance());
        list.forEach(Instance::InstanceMethod)
    }
}
```

Output: `Hello World`

C#:

```cs
public class Instance{
    public void InstanceMethod(){Console.WriteLine("Hello World");}
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Action<T> action){
        foreach(T item in input){
            action(item);
        }
    }
    public static void Example(){
        List<Instance> list = new ArrayList<>(5);
        list.Add(new Instance());
        list.ForEach(Instance.InstanceMethod);//error need instance to call method
    }
```

Comment: Given that you've just shown how to do it in C#, what's your question?

Comment: @Servy That is how it is done in Java

Comment: Your question provides a snippet of both java and C# code that does this, the former in the second sentence, the latter in the second to last sentence.

Comment: @Servy I have added a clarification. I want to be able to do it without using a Lambda expression.

Comment: I think the parameter should either be a delegate, which matches that method. Or do you need to specifically only allow methods from a particular class?

Comment: I think you can look at Action or Function concept in C#

Comment: Do you really need a list of `Instance`s? What if you just store a list of methods and then simply call them?

Comment: Your comment is that you don't want to use lambda because the method may have arguments, but how would you pass those arguments using only the method as the parameter to ForEach?

Comment: @Nikki9696 For `DoSomething(Func<Instance,bool,bool,bool,bool,bool,bool,bool,bool> method)` you do `DoSomething(Instance.BoolMethod)`. The `ForEach` is just an example.

Comment: @Nikki9696 It appears I misunderstood your comment. The idea is that the compiler handles the details and assumes the first type in the delegate is the item to call the method on and everything else is for method parameters.

Comment: I can think of a variety of ways to accomplish this, but nothing that is a direct translation like the Java example. Lambdas, reflection, method groups, Func<T> etc. Even making your own extension method that could be used like your example, but you'd have to write it. It's not out of the box, as far as I know. If you'd like any examples, let us know, but I think your question was more about out of the box options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in Java you are still dealing with an instance, but Java's [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) hides that.

There is no equivalent for your case. You have to do

```
public static void Example()
{
    var list = new List<Instance>(5);
    list.Add(new Instance());
    list.ForEach(x => x.InstanceMethod());
}
```

or add`static` to`InstanceMethod` (since that method has no state):

```
public static void InstanceMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}

public static void Example()
{
    var list = new List<Instance>(5);
    list.Add(new Instance());
    list.ForEach(x => InstanceMethod());
}
```

If your `InstanceMethod` accepted an `Instance` as a parameter and `Example` *wasn't* static, there is some C# syntactic sugar called a [method group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c) that would work:

```
public void InstanceMethod(Instance x)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}

public void Example()
{
    var list = new List<Instance>(5);
    list.Add(new Instance());
    list.ForEach(InstanceMethod);
}
```

Of all of the above, the first one is idiomatic C# and the one I would pick. It's probably the most readable and expected for C# programmers to read.