# How can I pass parameters to queued background task (.NET Core)

Tags: .net, .net-core, background-process, self-hosting

In my web-application I have action with long-running task and I want to call this task in background. So, according to documentation .NET Core 3.1 [Queued background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks) I use such code for this:

```
public interface IBackgroundTaskQueue
{
    ValueTask QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask> workItem);

    ValueTask<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>> DequeueAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public class BackgroundTaskQueue : IBackgroundTaskQueue
{
    private readonly Channel<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>> _queue;

    public BackgroundTaskQueue(int capacity)
    {
        var options = new BoundedChannelOptions(capacity){FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.Wait};
        _queue = Channel.CreateBounded<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>>(options);
    }

    public async ValueTask QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask> workItem)
    {
        if (workItem == null)throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
        await _queue.Writer.WriteAsync(workItem);
    }

    public async ValueTask<Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>> DequeueAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var workItem = await _queue.Reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken);
        return workItem;
    }
}
```

And hosted service

```
public class QueuedHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<QueuedHostedService> _logger;

    public QueuedHostedService(IBackgroundTaskQueue taskQueue, ILogger<QueuedHostedService> logger)
    {
        TaskQueue = taskQueue;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IBackgroundTaskQueue TaskQueue { get; }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await BackgroundProcessing(stoppingToken);
    }

    private async Task BackgroundProcessing(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var workItem = await TaskQueue.DequeueAsync(stoppingToken);

            try
            {
                await workItem(stoppingToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error occurred executing {WorkItem}.", nameof(workItem));
            }
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Queued Hosted Service is stopping.");
        await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

then I register all services

```
services.AddHostedService<QueuedHostedService>();
services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundTaskQueue>(new BackgroundTaskQueue(queueCapacity));
```

then I can success use this by calling without params like in such sample

```
public async Task<TenantBo> RegisterCompanyAsync(AddTenantBo addTenantBo)
{
  var tenantBo = new TenantBo();

  try
  {
    _companyRegistrationLogHelper.SetInfoLog(GetTenantId(tenantBo), 
      "Start create company: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(addTenantBo));

      InitOnCreateCompanyTasks(tenantBo);

      //skip if already create tenant 
      tenantBo = await CreateTenantAsync(tenantBo, addTenantBo);

      //run in background
      _companyRegistationQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(RunRegistrationCompanyMainAsync);

      return tenantBo;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    //some logs
    return tenantBo;
  }
}

private async ValueTask RunRegistrationCompanyMainAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  //some await Tasks
}

private async ValueTask RunRegistrationCompanyMainAsync(string tenantId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  //some await Tasks
}
```

so I can call only RunRegistrationCompanyMainAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) with one param and cannot call RunRegistrationCompanyMainAsync(string tenantId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) with two params

Can u help me to pass string param as argument for this task?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In `QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(RunRegistrationCompanyMainAsync)` call compiler actually performs [cast from method group into a delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15125221/2501279). But to provide instance of [`Func`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-5.0) delegate your are not limited to method groups, you can provide a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) for example:

```
 var someTenantId = ....
 .....
_companyRegistationQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(ct => RunRegistrationCompanyMainAsync(someTenantId, ct));
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not enough. I need extend Func  and use Tuple

Comment: @NikitaSychou what do you mean by "not enough"?

Comment: Channel<Func<string, CancellationToken, ValueTask>> not enough but Channel<Tuple<string, Func<string, CancellationToken, ValueTask>>> and use in all places is enough

Comment: @NikitaSychou with my solution you don't need `Func<string, CancellationToken, ValueTask>`, you use the same  `Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask>` as for parameterless job. Your `Tuple` solution is almost the same what compiler actually does with closures as in my solution but with more hassle.

Comment: @GuruStron that worked for me a 100%

Comment: Worked for me too. I needed to pass the session user to a work item. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After some time I found solution.
Just  need to use Tuple like this

```
public class CompanyRegistationQueue : ICompanyRegistationQueue
    {
        private readonly Channel<Tuple<CreateCompanyModel, Func<CreateCompanyModel, CancellationToken, ValueTask>>> _queue;

        public CompanyRegistationQueue(int capacity)
        {
            var options = new BoundedChannelOptions(capacity) { FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.Wait };
            _queue = Channel.CreateBounded<Tuple<CreateCompanyModel, Func<CreateCompanyModel, CancellationToken, ValueTask>>**>(options);
        }

        public async ValueTask QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(Tuple<CreateCompanyModel, Func<CreateCompanyModel, CancellationToken, ValueTask>> workItem)
        {
            if (workItem == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
            await _queue.Writer.WriteAsync(workItem);
        }

        public async ValueTask<Tuple<CreateCompanyModel, Func<CreateCompanyModel, CancellationToken, ValueTask>>> DequeueAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var workItem = await _queue.Reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken);
            return workItem;
        }
    }
```

and then call it like this

```
private async Task BackgroundProcessing(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var workItem = await TaskQueue.DequeueAsync(stoppingToken);

                try
                {
//item2 is task
                    await workItem.Item2(workItem.Item1, stoppingToken);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex, "Error occurred executing {WorkItem}.", nameof(workItem));
                }
            }
        }
```

invoke in code

```
var paramValue = new Tuple<CreateCompanyModel, Func<CreateCompanyModel, CancellationToken, ValueTask>>(createCompanyModel, RunRegistrationCompanyMainAsync);
                await _companyRegistationQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(paramValue);
```

P.S. May by Tuple not best solution but its work