# How do you do a "ToUpper" on all char in a list in a single line in C#?

Tags: c#, char, toupper

I was tasked with this assignement but I cannot figure out how to do it.
I have a list of characters and I have to return a new list with the same contents except all the characters that are lowercase are changed to uppercases.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean you have a `List<char>` and want all entries uppercased, use LINQ and lambda expressions.

```
var chars = new List<char> {'a', 'b', 'c'};
var newList = chars.Select(Char.ToUpper).ToList();
```

`Select` invokes `Char.ToUpper()` on all entries and `ToList()` converts the result back to a list.

Comment: Thanks, this might be what I'm looking for.
On the microsoft documentation for Select, there is "IEnumerable<int> squares =
    Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => x * x);"
Is something akin to the (x => ...) necessary?

Comment: `chars.Select(x => Char.ToUpper(x))` is equivalent to `chars.Select(Char.ToUpper)` in this case, the latter is using a method group. See this question for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c

Answer (score -1):

i recommend reading this [article](https://www.javatpoint.com/program-to-replace-lower-case-characters-with-upper-case-and-vice-versa), it simply says that you have to check if the char case is lower and then make it upper using the following code

```
string str1="Great Power";  
        char ch;  
        System.Text.StringBuilder str2 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();  

for(int i = 0; i < str1.Length; i++) {  
            //Checks for lower case character  
            if(char.IsLower(str1[i])) {  
                //Convert it into upper case using ToUpper() function  
                ch = Char.ToUpper(str1[i]);  
                //Append that character to new character  
                str2.Append(ch);  
            }
```