# How to run delegate based on dictionary (C#)

Tags: c#, linq, action, func

I have Mock class with below:

```
private readonly List<SomeObject> m_objectsList = new List<SomeObject>();

public Task<IList<Auto>> Todo(SomeParams params)
{
 IEnumerable<Auto> matches = m_objectsList.Select(GetMyObject);
 return Task.FromResult<IList<Auto>>(matches.ToArray());
}

private Auto GetMyObject(SomeObject s)
{
 Auto newAuto = new Auto
 {
     Id = s.Id,
     Name = s.Name,
 };    
 return newAuto;
}
```

This is working OK. Now I want to do like:

```
private readonly Dictionary<SomeObject, SomeParams> m_objectsList2 = 
                                                 new Dictionary<SomeObject, SomeParams>();

public Task<IList<Auto>> Todo2(SomeParams params)
{
 IEnumerable<Auto> matches = m_objectsList2.Select(GetMyObject2);
 return Task.FromResult<IList<Auto>>(matches.ToArray());
}

private Auto GetMyObject2(SomeObject s, SomeParams p)
 {
  Auto newAuto = new Auto();
     ....//some code
     return newAuto;
 }
```

but getting Compiler Error CS0411.

Comment: I don't see how your code can work. You have too many type errors. Why is the name `m_objectsList2` when it is `Dictionary<>`? Why do you think `GetMyObject2` matches the signature of the `Func<>` required as a paramter for `Select`? What are the types you haven't defined?

Comment: `Dictionary<SomeObject, SomeParams>` is the wrong structure for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0) implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, and compiler can't perform [method group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c) conversion to delegate due to type mismatch. Either switch from using method group to lambda:

```cs
IEnumerable<Auto> matches = m_objectsList2.Select(kvp => GetMyObject2(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
```

Or change signature of the method (or add an overload):

```cs
private Auto GetMyObject2(KeyValuePair<SomeObject, SomeParams> kvp)
{
     var (s, p) = kvp; // use deconstruction
     // or for older compilers/framework versions
     // var s = kvp.Key;
     // var p = kvp.Value;
     Auto newAuto = new Auto();
     ....//some code
     return newAuto;
}
```

Comment: What delegate type do you expect the method group `GetMyObject2` to convert to here?

Comment: @JonSkeet  missed that another method was used, thank you.  Fixed.

Comment: how to to deconstruction of var(s, p) = kvp?

Comment: @4est added code (commented out) for older compilers/.NET versions.

Answer (score 0):

Can try modifying your Todo2

```
public Task<IList<Auto>> Todo2()
{
   // Removed params parameter as I don't see the usage. Please add back if you need it
    return Task.FromResult<IList<Auto>>(m_objectsList2.Select(p => GetMyObject2(p.Key, p.Value)).ToArray());
}
```