# cannot convert method grup "tostring"

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is my code
GetComponent ().text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("skor").ToString;

error: cannot convert method grup "tostring" to non dellegate type "string"

I don't know, why? Please give me solution of this

Comment: because you need to call it like this "ToString();" you see you are missing the parenthesis

Comment: Also just as advice... you should search google and study before asking in stackoverflow.

Comment: -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729642/int-to-string-cannot-convert-from-method-group-to-string

Answer (score 1):

type

```
ToString()
```

if you need an answer like this, i recommend the [unity scripting api](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/).